# Update Links to External Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet, excel-2016

I have a workbook that contains that contains links to one external workbook.  When I open the non-external workbook, excel tells me: "We can't update some of the links in your workbook right now".
The external workbook is closed, but the path exists and is correct within the *Edit Links* dialog box.  (for good measure I can even click change source and choose the external file).  The Status of this link always shows: "Error: Worksheet Not Found."

Upon clicking "Update Values", a second dialog box appears which says:

[Select Sheet]

Worksheet: DataLists

Workbook: DataLists.xlsm

"Select the sheet to update the values *from*" is a list of worksheets within the *active workbook*, not worksheets in the linked external workbook.  I do not have, nor link to, a worksheet called DataLists.

Since excel already has the correct file path to the external workbook, what is this error and how do I correct it?

Comment: links could exist in a named range or table. Look there as well.

Comment: no links in named ranges.  Links do exist in a table in the active workbook to cells in a table in the external workbook.